# delete a document in firebase when you know the field value

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Context: In the frontend the user can enter of delete dates for availability. This is how I added a date:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('availableDates').add({
        'availableDates':date});
```

But I also need to delete a `document` from a `collection` in `Firestore`. I don't know the `document` id but I know the the field `value` which is unique. How would I go about deleting the document if I know the field value within the document. Here is a screen shot of firestore:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can fetch the document first and then delete the document. For example:

```dart
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('countries');
var snapshot = await collection.where('city', isEqualTo: 'CA').get();
await snapshot.docs.first.reference.delete();
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is confused after the update of why this code is not working please refer to this one. Update of March 21st, 2021.

```
refUser.where("city", isEqualTo: "CA").get().then((snapshot){
snapshot.docs.first.reference.delete();
});
```

I took a bit of time myself to get around this but if it helps even a single person stuck like me then it's all worth it. :)