# How to delete Documents by Value name?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible in Firestore to delete some documents, where the "Value Name" is the same?

For example: I have some UID's as Documents inside a Collection. Inside these Documents will be saved two types of "Value Names". 1st "Value Name" is called "byCar". 2nd "Value Name" is called "byFoot". Now I want to delete all Documents, where the "Value Name" is equal to "byCar". All other documents, where the "Value Name" is "byFoot" will be untouched. Is something like this possible?

I program in Flutter / Dart and it would be awesome, if someone could provide me an answer, because I was not able to find somthing on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore doesn't support update queries, where you send a query to the server and it updates (or in your case deletes) all matching documents. To write or delete a document you will need to know its entire path in your application code.

So that means you need to perform two steps to delete the documents:

1. Execute a query to find all documents matching your condition.
2. Loop over the results and delete them.

In code that'd be something like:

```
refUser.where("city", isEqualTo: "CA").getDocuments().then((querySnapshot){
  for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in querySnapshot.documents){
    documentSnapshot.reference.delete();
  });
  snapshot.documents.first.reference.delete();
});
```

Also see:

- [delete a document in firebase when you know the field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56341378/delete-a-document-in-firebase-when-you-know-the-field-value)
- [How to Delete all documents in collection in Firestore with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53089517/how-to-delete-all-documents-in-collection-in-firestore-with-flutter)
- [How to update a single field of all documents in firestore using flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63321875/how-to-update-a-single-field-of-all-documents-in-firestore-using-flutter/63321904#63321904)

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand, thats maybe the reason why I was not able to finde something on the Internet haha. I will try it out. :)

Comment: I included some links I found by searching for "updating multiple documents" here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks again, I see that my search request was wrong...

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wrote a little bit of a mess. I meant, that I have searched for the wrong thing on the internet, so I was not able to find a solution by my own. Thank you for your time and help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code would look something like this:

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await db
  .collection("yourPathCollection")
  .where("Value Name", isEqualTo: "byCar")
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) {
querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
  doc.reference.delete();
});
return null; });
```

Perhaps Cloud Firestore will block your request, so you will need to change your database rules, according to your need.

Comment: Thank you very much, I guess I have looked for something like your code. I will try out and will write later if its worked. :)

Comment: I already tested this code in a similar example and it worked, if it works for you, please mark this answer as useful :)

Comment: I marked your answer and thank you for your help! :)